# Prevent Notepad++ from highlighting javascript code

Tags: javascript, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I don't mind syntax coloring, but I find it very annoying that Notepad++ highlights entire blocks of Javascript code, effectively dimming them and making it difficult to read. This is what it looks like:

[image: Notepad highlight javascript]

As you can see it shades the entire block of javascript with a purple color. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to **Settings > Style Configurator**.
- From the languages list select JavaScript.
- Go through each option in the 'Style' list, changing the background colour to white.

[image]